# Proof for the comparision criterio of uniform convergence

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, proof-writing

I'm trying find proof (or prove) for the following statement:

> For every $x \in M$ and every $n \in \mathbb{N}:$
>
> $|f_n(x)|\leq g_n(x)$
>
> If series of functions $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n$ converges uniformly
>   on $M$, then also series of functions $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$
>   converges uniformly on $M$.

I have been looking for proof for some time but didn't find it. If there is none, could you help me prove it?

Thanks

Comment: For all $\epsilon>0$ there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m>N$ and $x\in M$ one has $\epsilon>|\sum_{k=1}^{n}g_k(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{m}g_k(x)|\geq=\sum_{k=1}^{n}g_k(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{m}g_k(x)\geq|\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{m}f_k(x)|$. Therefore, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$ converges for all $x\in M$. Now, for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$ and $x\in M$ one has $\epsilon>|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}g_k(x)|=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}g_k(x)\geq\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}|f_k(x)|\geq|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}g_k(x)|=|\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f_k(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)|$.

Comment: What do you mean by "converges uniformly on $M$"? $M$ is just a real number. Did you mean $[-M,M]$?

Comment: @Math1000 $M$ is a set.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question.

Comment: @OscarRascal Thanks.